# How can we combine different deep learning models?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, ensemble-learning

I know that ensembles can be made by combining sklearn models with a VotingClassifier, but is it possible to combine different deep learning models? Will I have to make something similar to Voting Classifiers?